# Firebase Web - correct way to check login status during session

Tags: firebase, session, webpack, vue.js, firebase-authentication

Recently I have started implementing `Firebase` on `Vue webpack` project.

In order to check for user login on must do:

```
firebase.auth().currentUser
```

and receive either the User or null.

This is explicit for first time login but is it also the correct way to check for user login status throughout the session, to show/hide DOM elements depending on login status for example?

It works but is it the most efficient?

I also tried to save a flag to `sessionStorage` but that flag can be deleted with page refresh and can be bypassed. Am I correct to assume that for any check that requires security I should do `firebase.auth()` and for any check that is necessary for UI I can use session storage flag?

Is there any third, better option?

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, it depends what are you looking for. If you are looking at watch and dispatch an event if the user is logged or not, I think is better use this listener.

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {...... }
```

Where, `user` is the user logged or not. Maybe, it's a little similar to what you're saying. However, this Is the way I do when I need to play with this kind of operations. Also, it's a little more clean than just use `firebase.auth().currentUser`